# Suggestions for creating a select box or dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, promise, dropdown

I want to create a dropdown for items.
But the Item table has more than 200K rows.
So i want to show around 50 rows in the dropdown and the rest can be retrieved from search option present in the dropdown.
Can someone suggest what is the best approach to implement this.
[image: Dropdown example]

Comment: Use a library (such as Select2) to search through the available options, but make sure you perform the filtering logic on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQueryUI widget for this. It doesn't have any parameter to limit your items to 50. But you can try this code

```
$("#your_element").autocomplete({ 
    source: function(request, response){
        var items = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(your_data_source, request.term);
        response(items.slice(0, 50));
    }
});
```

[Check this link: Autocomplete widget of jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using react you can use some build in library which will be your redeemer. Probably you are looking for something like [react-select](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/). Go visit their git hub page and simply implement it following their instructions.
Here is some example for you

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
const options = [
{ value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
{ value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
{ value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }];

export default class test extends Component {
state = {
    selectedOption: null,
};
handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
};
render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
        <Select
            value={selectedOption}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={options}
        />
    );
}
```